# cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name

Tags: powershell, recursion, rename

Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test\testsub" -Recurse -Include *.wav |  %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("$*.Directory.Name.Substring(4)"+"($*.Name).wav")}

produces error I do not understand

[ERROR] Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name.

Comment: What do you want to rename it into?

Comment: Please provide some more information, such as the original file names and what you want them renamed to.

Answer (score 1):

as others mentioned, one can only guess at what you are trying to accomplish, so here is my guess.

remove -whatif to make the changes happen

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\test\testsub' -Recurse -Include *.wav | % {rename-item $_.fullname $($_.directory.name.substring(0, 4) + '-' + $_.name) -whatif}
```

Comment: This was the answer although I do not yet understand why. The attempt was to use the first four characters of the directory name to rename files contained within. Thanks to Mr Stringer.